# Django ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: gouri24>>": "HotelConfirm.username" must be a "userLogin" instance

Tags: django

I am encountering a ValueError in my Django project when trying to assign a user instance to the `username` field of the `HotelConfirm` model. The error message is:

"Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: gouri24>>": "HotelConfirm.username" must be a "userLogin" instance."

Here is a snippet of my code:

```py
# Your relevant code snippet here
login_required
def book_hotel(request, hotel_id):
    hotel = get_object_or_404(Hotel, pk=hotel_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Process the form submission
        user_instance = request.user  # Use the user instance directly
        room_type = request.POST.get('roomType')
        arrival = request.POST.get('arrival')
        departure = request.POST.get('departure')
        adult = request.POST.get('adult')
        children = request.POST.get('children')

        booking = HotelConfirm.objects.create(
            username=user_instance,
            hotel=hotel,
            roomType=room_type,
            arrival=arrival,
            departure=departure,
            adult=adult,
            children=children
        )
        booking.save()  # Save the booking object

        # Redirect to the home page after successful booking
        return redirect('home')  # Replace 'home' with the actual name or URL of your home page

    return render(request, 'Booking_hotel.html', {'hotel_id': hotel_id})


I am using Django's default User model, and it seems that there is a mismatch between the expected model for the username field (userLogin) and the actual user instance (<User: gouri24>). How can I resolve this issue and properly assign the user instance to the username field?
Make sure to include the relevant parts of your code that are related to the error, and provide additional context if necessary. This will help the community better understand your issue and provide you with accurate and helpful solutions.
```

Comment: please add HoltelConfirm model

Comment: Looks like the answer is in the error message: `"HotelConfirm.username" must be a "userLogin" instance."` - you're giving it a `User`.

Answer (score 0):

You must be logged in before creating this HotelConfirm instance
Make the post request after login and make sure your
models.py look like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class HotelConfirm(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Other fields
```